# How to toggle individual images?

Tags: javascript

The issue is that when I click on the questions the plus and minus icons of all the questions change, I only want the icon next to the question I clicked on to change. Can anyone help?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.questions');
const toggleIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon');


for (const question of questions) {
    question.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const answerToQuestion = question.nextElementSibling;
        answerToQuestion.toggleAttribute('hidden');
        for(const toggleIcon of toggleIcons) {
            if(toggleIcon.src == 'https://via.placeholder.com/50x50'){
                toggleIcon.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x200') 
            } else {
                toggleIcon.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/50x50')
            }
        } 
    })
}



});
```

```html
<div class='question-container'>
  <div class="questions">
    <h3>Can I return my order?</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon" onclick="openQuestion()">
  </div>
  <div class="answer" id="default-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
  <div class="questions">
    <h3>How much will it cost to ship my item?</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon" onclick="openQuestion()">
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactor the code to try to isolate some parts, it was as follows:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const QUESTIONS = document.querySelectorAll('.questions');
        const BIG_IMAGE_SRC = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200";
        const SMALL_IMAGE_SRC = "https://via.placeholder.com/50x50";

        for (let question of QUESTIONS) {
            question.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                const questionContainerDivTarget = this.parentElement;
                const imageTarget = questionContainerDivTarget.querySelector("img");
                const textTarget = questionContainerDivTarget.querySelector("p");
                const isTargetContainBigImage = imageTarget.src === BIG_IMAGE_SRC;

                textTarget.toggleAttribute("hidden");
                let toggleImage = isTargetContainBigImage ? SMALL_IMAGE_SRC : BIG_IMAGE_SRC;
               imageTarget.setAttribute("src", toggleImage);
            })
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class='question-container'>
    <div class="questions">
        <h3>Can I return my order?</h3>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="answer" id="default-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
            Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
    <div class="questions">
        <h3>How much will it cost to ship my item?</h3>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
            Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Be aware the `const questionContainerDivTarget = this.parentElement;` will get the `div` of the "question-container" css class. parentElement will get the first parent element and then you can control the entire div

Comment: This has worked but I would like to know "let toggleImage = isTargetContainBigImage ? SMALL_IMAGE_SRC : BIG_IMAGE_SRC;" this looks like an if statement, what is it called?

Comment: this is an ternary operator. You can check it in easily in google . It's the same as if condition. Example: if(isTargetContainBigImage){toggleImage = SMALL_IMAGE_SRC }else{toggleImage = BIG_IMAGE_SRC}. You'll find the ternary operator everywhere working with Javascript. See the link: [Conditional (Ternary) Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **perfect solution**

```
<div class='question-container'>
    <div class="questions">
      <h3>Can I return my order?</h3>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon" onclick="openQuestion(this)">
    </div>
    <div class="answer" id="default-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
        Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>
  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="question-container">
    <div class="questions">
      <h3>How much will it cost to ship my item?</h3>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon" onclick="openQuestion(this)">
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
        Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>
  
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is **script** you need

```
function openQuestion (e) {
    if(e.src == 'https://via.placeholder.com/50x50'){
        e.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x200') 
    } else {
        e.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/50x50')
    }
    e.parentNode.nextElementSibling.toggleAttribute('hidden')
}
```